# square table view cell constraint

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, autolayout, custom-cell

i have a problem with auto layout. I have UIImageView inside a cell. The image is square and i set the `cell height` to be `320`. but when i use iPad simulator, the cell height isn't change. it look like still use `320 height`.

I've try to set Bottom Margin and Top margin to be < or equal to `12` and set the `priority` to `1000` which is make the image in the correct size but the cell height isn't change.

question :
how i can set the cell height based on the device?
i use Swift.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can set the constant of your constraint to your customized height.
- Or use a custom cell height and then override the method `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat` to return the customized height based on your device type. And set the top, bottom, leading and trailing values to its superview bounds.

The second solution is as follows: set your constraints to the bounds
[image]
Then use a custom height [image]

And finally override the data source method

[image]

NB`let iPad = (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad)`

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer. can you please show me how i should use that? i'm newbie.. :)

Comment: i'm sorry, but what is iPad?

Comment: Something like "let iPad = (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad)"

Comment: btw, i've just found that i can use the screen width.. :) let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width and then return width.. :)

Comment: I know you can do that too. :) I thought you need to know the device type.